# Call to a CountDownTimer method pushes a Null pointer exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, static-methods, countdowntimer

I am working on a count down timer which seems to be spitting out  a null pointer exception when the method gets called. Please see below for the logcat output:

```
    01-02 21:26:50.772: D/AndroidRuntime(1743): Shutting down VM
    01-02 21:26:50.772: W/dalvikvm(1743): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4a72ba8)
    01-02 21:26:50.842: E/AndroidRuntime(1743): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    01-02 21:26:50.842: E/AndroidRuntime(1743): Process: com.vertygoeclypse.multitimer, PID: 1743
    01-02 21:26:50.842: E/AndroidRuntime(1743): java.lang.NullPointerException
    01-02 21:26:50.842: E/AndroidRuntime(1743):     at com.vertygoeclypse.multitimer.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:93)
    01-02 21:26:50.842: E/AndroidRuntime(1743):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
    01-02 21:26:50.842: E/AndroidRuntime(1743):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
    01-02 21:26:50.842: E/AndroidRuntime(1743):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    01-02 21:26:50.842: E/AndroidRuntime(1743):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    01-02 21:26:50.842: E/AndroidRuntime(1743):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    01-02 21:26:50.842: E/AndroidRuntime(1743):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    01-02 21:26:50.842: E/AndroidRuntime(1743):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    01-02 21:26:50.842: E/AndroidRuntime(1743):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    01-02 21:26:50.842: E/AndroidRuntime(1743):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    01-02 21:26:50.842: E/AndroidRuntime(1743):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    01-02 21:26:50.842: E/AndroidRuntime(1743):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    01-02 21:26:53.162: I/Process(1743): Sending signal. PID: 1743 SIG: 9
```

The logcat shows me that the null pointer exception comes from line 93 of my code and this line is below:

```
    countDownTimer.start();
```

That links to the below initializing statement:

```
    MultiCountDownTimer countDownTimer;
```

that leads us Now to this code that is pointing to a CountDownTimer with the onfinish() and onTick() overridden by my own lines, see below for the code in question:

```
        public class MultiCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer
{
    public MultiCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval)
        {
            super(startTime, interval);
        }
    @Override
    public void onFinish()
        {
            timeRemaining.setText("Time's up!");
            timeElapsedView.setText("Time Elapsed: " + String.valueOf(startTime));
        }
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
        {
            timeRemaining.setText("Time remain:" + millisUntilFinished);
            timeElapsed = startTime - millisUntilFinished;
            timeElapsedView.setText("Time Elapsed: " + String.valueOf(timeElapsed));
        }
}
```

I have the two requirements being set from values set in a dialogbox with numberpickers. I log.i the 2 place holder variables and they return the long values as required. See below for the code that sets the required values:

```
        long startTime=0;
long interval=1000;
long coversionvalues=0;
```

Those are the initializers.

```
            case R.id.submitbtn:
        tgview.setText(String.valueOf(tagvalue.getText()));
        minview.setText(String.valueOf(minnp.getValue()));
        secview.setText(String.valueOf(secnp.getValue()));
        int val1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(minnp.getValue()));
        int val2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(secnp.getValue()));
        int val3 = (val1*60)*1000;
        int val4 = val2*1000;
        coversionvalues = Long.valueOf(String.valueOf(val3+val4));
        startTime = coversionvalues;
        starest.setEnabled(true);
        cusd.dismiss(); 
        break;
```

That is the case within a switch that works with the onclick to get the values set them to some place holders on the screen, as well as convert the numberpicker values to long for the CountDownTimer. after that the nutton to start the count down is enabled and the dialog box is dismissed. then the case is broken. This works fine it is the portion with the starting the timer that lead me to this point.

Any assistance that you all can render would be greatly appreciated.

regards

cchinchoy

Comment: obviously your countDownTimer is null at that point, is it meant to be null, or did u maybe miss something? cant tell since i cant see the relevant code :)
would need the MainActivity to b able to tell you why it might be null, only thing i can do now is tell you to initialize it ^^

Comment: Daniel thanks yes it was null, being new to android programming, my assumption was that the declaration statement above the oncreate was the initializing stage. but Funkthemonk below pointed out that the declaration is not an initialize and it has to be done as separate steps. Thanks for the assist of your knowledge. I will comment further on the progress of this.

Comment: it doesnt have to be seperate steps, as he shows, it can be done in a single step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MultiCountDownTimer countDownTimer;
```

Is not an initialising statement (it is a decleration statement).

```
MultiCountDownTimer countDownTimer = new MultiCountDownTimer();
```

Would be, where do you initialise countDownTimer, and does it occur before the onClick code?

Comment: No it occurs after the on click happens.

Comment: can I also do this `MultiCountDownTimer countDownTimer;` as the declaration statement and then below after the onCreate put in `countDownTimer = new MultiCountDownTimer();` if that would work it would help a lot.

Comment: ok I think I got it, when I placed my declaration above I added private to it, `private MultiCountDownTimer countDownTimer;` and this allowed me to initialize it as, `countDownTimer = new MultiCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);` and this cleared the errors I was seeing. I am running it now and seeing if it works, thanks for point it out to me.

Comment: Ok thanks much this works and answers my question, however I am only seeing the onFinish items showing up. I believe that the timer is working, however I am not seeing the updates in the onTick, I will investigate and try and rectify. Once I get it resolved I will post how in the comments section here. Although it may not be related to the question that was asked, but I believe that it will assist in a situation where this question is asked and other users experience the same issue.  regards cchinchoy